# Sound problems 18.04

Tags: 18.04

After the last update I lost the sound in videos and music, but the alerts of my lap do sound. I have version 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: please do a `sudo apt upgrade`!

Comment: Ya hice el upgrade pero sigue sin funcionar el sonido en música y videos. Si hago la prueba en la configuración si suena el sonido.